# for all $x$, $P(x)$ implies there exists $x$, $P(x)$?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, quantifiers

$$\begin{align*}
\big[\forall x\,P(x)\to\exists x\,P(x)\big]&\iff\left[\big(\neg\forall x\,P(x)\big)\lor\exists x\,P(x)\right]\\
&\iff\exists x\,\neg P(x)\lor\exists x\,P(x)\;,
\end{align*}$$

so is

$$\forall x\,P(x)\to\exists x\,P(x)$$

true?

Comment: As long as there is a nonempty universe.

Comment: since there exists x,P(x) is false  for empty domain and also there exists x,~P(x)  is false for empty domain. for all x, P(x) implies there exists x, P(x) should be false for empty domain . hence non empty universe only right.

Comment: In mathematical proofs, quantifiers are almost always restricted to some set. Universal quantifiers: $\forall x\in S: P(x)$ or equivalently $\forall x:[x\in S \to P(x)]$. Existential quantifiers: $\exists x\in S: P(x)$ or equivalently $\exists x:[x\in S \land P(x)]$. Using this convention, it is obvious that $\exists x\in S: P(x)$ follows from $\forall x\in S: P(x)$ only if $S$ is non-empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, both (1) and (2) are valid first-order sentences:

1. $$\vDash ∀xP(x)→∃xP(x)$$
2. $$\vDash ∃x¬P(x)∨∃xP(x)$$

which means that they hold for every model $M$ of the concerned language.

What you are probably concerned about is the **[ontological comitment](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/ontological-commitment/)** underlying both sentences, namely, the existential presupposition of objects that we made when asserting them. (For instance (2) says that, for every property $P$, *there exists* a guy that either have it or not.)

But note that this **existential presupposition** of first order logic is nothing but a technical consequence of the constraint that the universe of $M$ must be **non-empty**. Is there a reason why it is so? Well, because it is useful. Particularly, note that without this constraint we would have to change the inference rules of natural deduction, in order to guarantee **soundness**.

Alternatively, you can also look for [free logics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_logic), a non-classical variant of first order logic that may allow for a domain to be empty (and, also, may allow for terms to not denote any object).

Comment: I had this doubt of how the rules were for empty domain. So in halmos naive set theory is free logic used?

Comment: @Arjun See page 8. There Halmos introduces the **Axiom of Existence**: *there exists a set that contains no elements*. In fact, it is impossible to do set theory without some axiom of this sort, since one cannot simple create sets out of nothing. In other words, Halmos' domain can't be empty at all.

Comment: while reading about vacuous truth I understood that we can take for an empty domain far all x, P(x) as vacuously true. But are we assuming the theorem of logic that (x) P(x) <=> ~(there exists x)~ P(x) true for empty domain then prove for existential quantifier over empty domain P(x) is false? OR are we assuming (there exists x)P(x) as false for empty domain then prove theorem of logic works for empty domain also ?

Comment: @Arjun Yes, for an empty domain, $\forall x P(x)$ could be taken as valid (it would had no counterexample model). But if the logic you are mentioning is the first-order logic, note that those questions cannot be even formulated, since the domain, *by definition*, cannot be empty.

Comment: yes, in free logic which one is assumed the theorem of logic or the existential quantifier one? we can prove from one that other holds .

Comment: @Arjun Formally, $\forall x P(x) \rightarrow \exists x P(x)$ is substituted  by $\forall x P(x) \land \exists ! t \rightarrow \exists x P(x)$ in free logic, where $\exists ! t$ is sometimes defined as $\exists y (y=t)$. But for more information, you can refer to the [Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy entry on it](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-free/#2).