# Does universal quantifier implies existential quantifier?

Tags: logic, quantifiers

is it true to state:
$$\forall  \implies \exists $$

If yes, why does this statement is neither mentioned in textbooks neither on the internet. I could not find this statement on a single wikipedia page related to quantifiers or a regular course about logic.

I only found a single place on the internet that mentions it : [Does existential quantifier include universal quantifier?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2690787/does-existential-quantifier-include-universal-quantifier)
But the reply in that page doesn't prove it, only saying "according to standard semantics".

Comment: If the domain is nonempty, yes. If the domain is empty, no.

Comment: Searching "does for all imply exists" in this very site yields [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1297521/for-all-x-px-implies-there-exists-x-px). So, perhaps not so much that it is "neither mentioned in textbooks neither on the internet" and more "I could not figure out how to locate it"?

Comment: And using Google, I find [this](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/for-all-x-px-implies-there-exists-some-x-px.63641/).

Comment: I was searching with the "quantifier" term. I also searched with the ∀⟹∃ formula, but it seems google struggles to index those formulas since they are not always text based. You found those links by using the word "for all", without using the word "quantifier". And I did check multiple textbooks in my own language and they didnt mention it. Wikipedia also has articles for both existential and universal, and they even mention negation and combination, but never implication from universal to existential @ArturoMagidin

Comment: For nonempty domains, the implication is an easy consequence of first doing [universal instantiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_instantiation) followed by [existential generalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existential_generalization). For empty domains, the consequent is necessarily false and the antecedent necessarily true, so the implication does not hold.

Comment: See [Natural Deduction: Rules for Quantifiers](https://iep.utm.edu/nat-ded/#H7): from $\forall x Px$ to $Pa$ by $(\forall \text E)$ and from $Pa$ to $\exists x Px$ by $(\exists \text I)$.

Comment: In mathematical proofs, quantifiers are almost always restricted to some set. Universal quantifiers: $\forall x\in S: P(x)$ or equivalently $\forall x:[x\in S \to P(x)]$. Existential quantifiers: $\exists x\in S: P(x)$ or equivalently $\exists x:[x\in S \land P(x)]$. Using this convention, it is obvious that $\exists x\in S: P(x)$ follows from $\forall x\in S: P(x)$ only if $S$ is non-empty.